# Firebase retrieve data dynamically

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, native

## Question

I am trying to display data from my firebase depending on what day of the week it is. My firebase children have the title of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 for the days of the isoWeek with a value of random words. My question is, how do I retrieve just mondays data if its monday? Code is below

## React Native Code

```
 var MY VARIABLE = moment().isoWeekday(); //Friday is 5
 var items = [];
  snap.forEach((child) => {
   
    items.push({
      title: child.val().title,
      profile:child.val().profile,
      test:child.val().test,
      special:child.val().today, //,<---- I want this child.val().MY VARIABLE
      _key: child.key,
    });
  });'
```

## Firebase

```
  "myWords" : {
    "words" : {
      "1" : "Tool box",
      "2" : "Ice Cream",
      "3" : "Lavender",
      "4" : "Speakers",
      "5" : "Pepsi",
      "6" : "Windows",
      "7" : "Linux",
    }
  }
```

So say for example its friday, or 5. I want to  retrieve child.val().5 with a variable. Is this achievable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is definitely achievable!

Try: `child.val()[variable]`

In javascript, we can access an object's properties by either using dots or brackets. For example, `object.property` or `object["property"]`.

Again, in your case, to access the firebase element with a variable, you could do `child.val()[variable]` where variable is some string or integer to access the firebase object's property. Perhaps variable = 5 or variable = '5'.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace child.val().today  ---> child.val()[MY VARIABLE]

```
var MY_VARIABLE = moment().isoWeekday(); //Friday is 5
 var items = [];
  snap.forEach((child) => {

    items.push({
      title: child.val().title,
      profile:child.val().profile,
      test:child.val().test,
      special:child.val()[MY_VARIABLE],
      _key: child.key,
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're going to be struggling with how the Firebase client handles arrays here.

The Firebase client will interpret your data as an array and convert it to:

```
"myWords" : {
  "words" : [
    null,
    "Tool box",
    "Ice Cream",
    "Lavender",
    "Speakers",
    "Pepsi",
    "Windows",
    "Linux",
  ]
}
```

So it inserts an empty value in the first position of the array. If that is not a problem for your app, then you can accept this.

But for many apps this extra item is a problem. In those cases, we recommend that you prefix your numbers with some fixed string to ensure Firebase doesn't does its string interpretation:

```
"myWords" : {
  "words" : {
    "item1" : "Tool box",
    "item2" : "Ice Cream",
    "item3" : "Lavender",
    "item4" : "Speakers",
    "item5" : "Pepsi",
    "item6" : "Windows",
    "item7" : "Linux",
  }
}
```

See this blog post for more information about how Firebase handles arrays: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html